# Не создается topic KAfka

Tags: java, apache-kafka

Всем привет.
У меня есть приложение, которое работает с Stream Kafka.

Я в нем также пытаюсь создать топики но получаю ошибку:

> INFO Terminate ZkClient event thread. (org.I0Itec.zkclient.ZkEventThread:83) 
>   
> INFO Session: 0x1000000b299004d closed (org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper:684) 
>   
> INFO EventThread shut down for session: 0x1000000b299004d (org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn:519) 
>   
> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/kafka/common/protocol/SecurityProtocol
>           at kafka.server.Defaults$.(KafkaConfig.scala:120)
>           at kafka.server.Defaults$.(KafkaConfig.scala)
>           at kafka.log.Defaults$.(LogConfig.scala:29)
>           at kafka.log.Defaults$.(LogConfig.scala)
>           at kafka.log.LogConfig$.(LogConfig.scala:137)
>           at kafka.log.LogConfig$.(LogConfig.scala)
>           at kafka.admin.AdminUtils$.createOrUpdateTopicPartitionAssignmentPathInZK(AdminUtils.scala:268)
>           at kafka.admin.AdminUtils$.createTopic(AdminUtils.scala:237)
>           at kafka.admin.AdminUtils.createTopic(AdminUtils.scala)
>           at com.testStockStreams.PropertiesConfig.createTopic(PropertiesConfig.java:38)
>           at com.testStockStreams.StreamsApplication.main(StreamsApplication.java:23)
>       Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.kafka.common.protocol.SecurityProtocol
>           at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
>           at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
>           at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:349)
>           at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
>           ... 11 more
>       Process finished with exit code 1

Ошибка возникает в строке класса `PropertiesConfig` во время попытки создать топик:

```
AdminUtils.createTopic(zkUtils, topicName, 10, 1, new Properties());
```

Подозреваю, что проблема в зависимостях, но найти решение никак не удается.

Буду очень благодарен за помощь. Код по тексту ниже:

pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.testStockStreams</groupId>
    <artifactId>test-stock-streams</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.kafka</groupId>
            <artifactId>kafka-streams</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.101tec</groupId>
            <artifactId>zkclient</artifactId>
            <version>0.10</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.kafka</groupId>
            <artifactId>kafka_2.11</artifactId>
            <version>0.9.0.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.kafka</groupId>
            <artifactId>kafka-streams-test-utils</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.0</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.12</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.25</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.3</version>
                <inherited>true</inherited>
                <configuration>
                    <source>${java.version}</source>
                    <target>${java.version}</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

*class PropertiesConfig*

```
package com.testStockStreams;


import kafka.admin.AdminUtils;
import kafka.utils.ZKStringSerializer$;
import kafka.utils.ZkUtils;
import org.I0Itec.zkclient.ZkClient;
import org.I0Itec.zkclient.ZkConnection;
import org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.ConsumerConfig;
import org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TopicExistsException;
import org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.Serdes;
import org.apache.kafka.streams.StreamsConfig;

import java.util.Properties;

public class PropertiesConfig {

    private final static String BOOTSTRAP_SERVER = "localhost:9092";
    private final static String ZK_SERVER = "localhost:2181";

    public static Properties initConfig() {
        Properties config = new Properties();
        config.put(StreamsConfig.APPLICATION_ID_CONFIG , "KafkaProducer");
        config.put(StreamsConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG , BOOTSTRAP_SERVER);
        config.put(ConsumerConfig.AUTO_OFFSET_RESET_CONFIG , "earliest");
        config.put(StreamsConfig.DEFAULT_KEY_SERDE_CLASS_CONFIG , Serdes.String().getClass());
        config.put(StreamsConfig.DEFAULT_VALUE_SERDE_CLASS_CONFIG , Serdes.Double().getClass());

        return config;
    }

    public static void createTopic(String topicName) {
        ZkClient zkClient = new ZkClient(ZK_SERVER, 10000, 10000, ZKStringSerializer$.MODULE$);

        ZkUtils zkUtils = new ZkUtils(zkClient, new ZkConnection(ZK_SERVER), false);

        try {
            AdminUtils.createTopic(zkUtils, topicName, 10, 1, new Properties());
        } catch (TopicExistsException e) {
            System.out.println("*** Topic '" + topicName + "' already exist.");
        } finally {
            zkClient.close();
        }
    }
}
```

*class StreamsApplication*

```
package com.testStockStreams;

import org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.Serdes;
import org.apache.kafka.streams.KafkaStreams;
import org.apache.kafka.streams.StreamsBuilder;
import org.apache.kafka.streams.Topology;
import org.apache.kafka.streams.kstream.KStream;
import org.apache.kafka.streams.kstream.KTable;

import java.util.Properties;

public class StreamsApplication {

    private final static String TOPIC_MASTER = "stock-topic-master";
    private final static String TOPIC_LAST_DATA = "stock-topic-last-data";
    private final static String TOPIC_LESS = "stock-topic-less";
    private final static String TOPIC_MORE = "stock-topic-more";
    private final static String TOPIC_AVERAGES_STATISTICAL = "stock-topic-averages";


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Properties config = PropertiesConfig.initConfig();
        PropertiesConfig.createTopic(TOPIC_LAST_DATA);
        PropertiesConfig.createTopic(TOPIC_LESS);
        PropertiesConfig.createTopic(TOPIC_MORE);
        PropertiesConfig.createTopic(TOPIC_AVERAGES_STATISTICAL);

        StreamsApplication streamsApp  = new StreamsApplication();
        KafkaStreams streams = new KafkaStreams(streamsApp.createTopology(), config);
        streams.start();

        Runtime.getRuntime().addShutdownHook(new Thread(streams::close));
    }

    public Topology createTopology() {
        StreamsBuilder builder = new StreamsBuilder();
        KStream<String, Double> quotes = builder.stream(TOPIC_MASTER);

        /* save latest data on quotes */
        KTable<String, Double> quotesSlice = quotes.groupByKey().reduce((previousValue, newValue) -> newValue);

        /* save average value of quotations in KTable */
        KTable<String, Long> countValues = quotes.groupByKey().count();
        KTable<String, Double> sumValues = quotes.groupByKey().reduce((v1, v2) -> v1 + v2);
        KTable<String, Double> averages = sumValues.join(countValues, (sum, count) -> sum/count.doubleValue());

        /* tables (1) and (2) need to be additionally merged into two topics in Kafka */
        averages.to(Serdes.String(), Serdes.Double(), TOPIC_AVERAGES_STATISTICAL);
        quotesSlice.to(Serdes.String(), Serdes.Double(), TOPIC_LAST_DATA);

        /* split the input stream of quotations into the other two and save them in two different topics,
           one where the value of the quotes> = 2.5, in another <2.5 */
        KStream<String, Double> valuesLess = quotes.filter((key, value) -> value < 2.5);
        valuesLess.to(Serdes.String(), Serdes.Double(), TOPIC_LESS);
        KStream<String, Double> valuesMore = quotes.filter((key, value) -> value >= 2.5);
        valuesMore.to(Serdes.String(), Serdes.Double(), TOPIC_MORE);

        return builder.build();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуйте `kafka_2.12` вместо `kafka_2.11`. Или возможно, что надо поменять `<version>`. Проблема в том, что `SecurityProtocol` передвинули в другой пакет (из `org.apache.kafka.common.protocol` в `org.apache.kafka.common.security.auth`) и если использовать несочетающиеся версии - класс грузится из неправильного пакета. Мне помогли вот эти списки версий:

- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.kafka/kafka
- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.kafka/kafka-clients
- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.kafka/kafka-streams